# Undefined offset Error with array of exploded strings

Tags: php, mysqli, explode

I'm having some trouble with what is probably a very simple problem, but I just can't get my head around what the issue is.

I used `fopen()` to load a csv file, and broke it down into its different rows, loading the strings into an array of strings. I am trying to break apart each string to plug the values into a sql database.

$datalength is the number of lines there are in my csv file. The first line are the headings of the columns, so $x begins at 1.

```
for ($x=1;$x<$datalength;$x++)
    {
        $broken = explode(",",$lines[$x]);
        $field1 = $broken[0];
        $field2 = $broken[1];
        $field3 = $broken[2];
        $field4 = $broken[3];
        echo $division;
        $importdata = "INSERT INTO Teams (Field1,Field2,Field3,Field4)
        Values ($field1,$field2,$field3,$field4)";
    }
```

I keep getting the following error (BTW, I'm using WAMP):

```
 Notice: Undefined offset: 1 in C:\wamp\www\test 2 (html-index)\upload_file.php on line 45, 46, 47
```

Lines 45-47 coincide with the `$field2`, `$field3`, and `$field4` allocations of `$broken[1]` through `$broken[3]`. I don't understand why that is.

Anything I'm missing right off the bat? Any suggestions you think might make my life much easier would be warmly appreciated.

Comment: have you tried `var_dump($broken)`? Maybe [1], [2], and [3] really are undefined offsets in that array.

Answer (score -1):

> Anything I'm missing right off the bat?

Yes.
Something quite essential.

You are a *virtual programmer*. Your program deals not with the real data but with imaginary one. You imagine that some string you have can be exploded and put into array. While it is not. But, for some reason, you remain in a virtual world of your imagination and make no attempt to get in touch with a real one.

You are assuming that `$lines[$x]` contains a comma delimited string. **Did you verify it?**
You are assuming that `$broken` contains an array of four elements. **Did you verify it?**

Just by printing them out. This is so easy yet it will bring you into the real world at once - you will see the **real** data you process, not imaginary one. And be able to take any appropriate measures.

`var_dump()` is a best programmer's friend. Please make friends with this indispensable function too.

```
var_dump($lines[$x],$broken);
```

will clearly tell you, what's wrong with your offsets.